# ASP.NET Mermbership.cs file Template

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, custom-membershipprovider

Is there any ASP.NET Membership file Template available ?

if it is not available how to write Custom Membership file from the Scratch... ?

Thanks in Adv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the methods you need to override for your membership provider. If you want to learn, you can decompile this [ASP.NET Universal Providers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx) using JetBrains's dotPeek or telerik JustDecompile; you will get DefaultMembershipProvider.cs (I cannot upload it as it is too long).

```
public class CustomMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{
    public override MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, string password, string email, string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved, object providerUserKey, out MembershipCreateStatus status)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer(string username, string password, string newPasswordQuestion, string newPasswordAnswer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override string GetPassword(string username, string answer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool ChangePassword(string username, string oldPassword, string newPassword)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override string ResetPassword(string username, string answer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void UpdateUser(MembershipUser user)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool UnlockUser(string userName)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override MembershipUser GetUser(object providerUserKey, bool userIsOnline)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override string GetUserNameByEmail(string email)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool DeleteUser(string username, bool deleteAllRelatedData)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override MembershipUserCollection GetAllUsers(int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override int GetNumberOfUsersOnline()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override MembershipUserCollection FindUsersByName(string usernameToMatch, int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override MembershipUserCollection FindUsersByEmail(string emailToMatch, int pageIndex, int pageSize, out int totalRecords)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool EnablePasswordRetrieval
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public override bool EnablePasswordReset
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public override bool RequiresQuestionAndAnswer
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public override string ApplicationName
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public override int MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public override int PasswordAttemptWindow
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public override bool RequiresUniqueEmail
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public override MembershipPasswordFormat PasswordFormat
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public override int MinRequiredPasswordLength
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public override int MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public override string PasswordStrengthRegularExpression
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey savior you are. yes i was expecting this answer for long time. i was expecting that DefaultMembershipProvider.cs thing... this is a great reply. thank you very much...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're talking about but [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165159/Custom-Membership-Providers) you have an good sample about how to implement a custom membership provider

On [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44w5aswa.aspx) you'll also find several resournces about this topic

Comment: sorry for that, now i updated my question and i hope this is clear.    Thank u.

Comment: @omm: I think links on my answer should help you. Please take a look to them.

Comment: Thanks  but my question is : is there any Predefined Membership file is available or we have to write on our own ?

MSDN says that we can write our own Custom Membership Files, so is there any Default Membership available ? where?